# C# REST API - POST Request: "You must provide a request body .."

Tags: c#, rest, api, http, post

I'm just trying to get a REST-API response from a POST request.

Getting this error:

> You must provide a request body if you set ContentLength>0 or
>   SendChunked==true. Do this by calling [Begin]GetRequestStream before
>   [Begin]GetResponse

Here is my code:

```
public enum httpVerb
{
    GET,
    POST,
    PUT,
    DELETE
}

class RestProvider
{
    public string uri { get; set; }
    public httpVerb httpMethod { get; set; }

    public RestProvider()
    {
        uri = "";
        httpMethod = httpVerb.POST;
    }

    public string makeRequest()
    {
        string strResponseValue = string.Empty;        
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = httpMethod.ToString();
        request.ContentLength = uri.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strResponseValue = "{\"errorMessages\":[\"" + ex.Message.ToString() + "\"],\"errors\":{}}";
        }

        finally
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                ((IDisposable)response).Dispose();
            }
        }

        return strResponseValue;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This: `request.ContentLength = uri.Length;` is wrong.  That's not what `ContentLength` is for.  Either leave `ContentLength` alone, (in which case it will be zero,) or send some request content and set `ContentLength` to the length of the request content that you are sending.  The `uri` is not a request content.

Comment: How do i get the length of the whole request?

Comment: `ContentLength` is not the length of the whole request.  It is the length of the ***request content***.  And you don't seem to be sending any ***request content***.  So leave `ContentLength` to zero.  If you were sending a ***request content***, then you would need to set `ContentLength` to be the length, in bytes, of the ***request content***.